# Displaying values from mysqli with loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, mysqli

I need to be able to display the `course_desc` on line 30, beside the `course_name`.

```
<?php

    $result = $db->query("select distinct c.dbid, c.course_name, c.course_image, m.module_id, m.module_name, m.module_name_id, m.module_image, m.hasFiles, m.files from courses c join modules_to_courses mc on (c.dbid = mc.courses_id) join modules m on (mc.modules_id = m.module_id)");

    $course_name = $db->query("SELECT distinct course_name, course_desc FROM courses");

    while ($temp = $course_name->fetch_assoc()) {
    $courses[] = $temp['course_name'];
    }

    $final = array();

    // Retrieve results
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    // Add to final array via counter if valid course is found
    if (in_array($row['course_name'], $courses)) {
        $final[$row['course_name']][] = $row;
        }

    }

    // Display if final array is not empty
    if (!empty($final)) {
    // Loop through each potential course name
    foreach ($courses as $name) {
        // Output if the course has values within the final array
        if (array_key_exists($name, $final)) {
        echo '<div>'."\n";
        echo ' '. $name . "\n";
        echo '<!--   list of modules   -->'."\n";
            // Loop through internal values
            foreach ($final[$name] as $value) {

            $module_name = $value['module_name'];

            echo ' '. $module_name ."\n";
            }
            echo ' </div>'."\n";
        }
    }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Please post the code here, don't link to external sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already having your course description in `$final` so you can access it using,

```
$final[$name]['course_desc']
```

I have created a [paste](http://pastebin.com/NYVxvw9p) based on your with changes. Also note that it's need to change your `$final` array.

Comment: Hi, This didn't display the course_desc. It also messed up the $module_name displaying

Comment: @Greystoke - forgot to mention you need to change the way you displaying module name too as `$final[$name][$value]`. Also check `var_dump($final)` to how exactly you getting

Comment: Also if you don't want to change your final array you should get description as `$final[$name][0]['course_desc']`.

Comment: $final[$name][0]['course_desc']; Was what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

distinct course_name, course_desc means you are trying to fetch the values regarding to distinct course_name and distinct course_desc together. You may wanna use group by instead. If I understood correctly, your statement will not bring you distinct course names and their related course desc. (if that is what you want)

Comment: So do I need to remove the 'distinct', from the second line